# Python: Number and operator concatenation not working (Euler's Method)

Tags: python, methods, replace, concatenation, eval

Whenever I run the following (Python) code, my attempt at Euler's method, I receive the following error:

> y += h * eval(diff_eq_solved); TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects.

The error is easy to understand, but I'm not sure where the problem lies since all items in split were converted to strings. My guess is that the + operator isn't included as a string, but I'm not sure how to fix this (maybe escaping?). Please help!

```
x = raw_input("What is your initial x? ")

y = raw_input("What is your initial y? ")

h = float(raw_input("What is your step size? "))
final_x = float(raw_input("At what value of x would you like to approximate the solution? "))
diff_eq = raw_input("What is your differential equation? ")
split = list(diff_eq)

while float(x) < final_x:
    def replace(split, X, Y):
        i = 0
        for v in split:
            if v == X:
                split.pop(i)
                split.insert(i, Y)
            i += 1
    replace(split, "x", str(x))
    replace(split, "y", str(y))
    diff_eq_solved = ''.join(split)
    y += h * eval(diff_eq_solved)
    x += h

if type(y) != int:
    print "Syntax Error."

print y
```

Comment: What input do you pass to the program to get this error?

Comment: I should've included that in the question! -_- silly me..

x = 0
y = 1
h = .5
final_x = 6
diff_eq = x+y

Comment: I guessed x=1 y=1 h=1 final=1 diff=x+y ... that worked well enough :)

Comment: I wish that was the case! Actually, the process should yield 3; 1 is just my function returning the input value (1). Which means I need to work on it some more (by fixing the error). At least it prints something though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can help yourself answer this question by doing:

`print type(y), type(h), type(eval(diff_eq_solved))`

You will find that the type of y is `str` - the documentation of raw_input says

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

... so you need to convert it to a float:

`y=float(raw_input(prompt))`

The resulting program looks like this:

```
x = float(raw_input("What is your initial x? "))

y = float(raw_input("What is your initial y? "))

h = float(raw_input("What is your step size? "))
final_x = float(raw_input("At what value of x would you like to approximate the solution? "))
diff_eq = raw_input("What is your differential equation? ")
split = list(diff_eq)

while float(x) < final_x:
    def replace(split, X, Y):
        i = 0
        for v in split:
            if v == X:
                split.pop(i)
                split.insert(i, Y)
            i += 1
    replace(split, "x", str(x))
    replace(split, "y", str(y))
    diff_eq_solved = ''.join(split)
    print type(y), type(h), type(eval(diff_eq_solved))
    y += h * eval(diff_eq_solved)
    x += h

if type(y) != int:
    print "Syntax Error."

print y
```

The resulting output looks like this:

```
(h2hh)~ mgregory$ python foo.py
What is your initial x? 0
What is your initial y? 1
What is your step size? 0.5
At what value of x would you like to approximate the solution? 6
What is your differential equation? x*y
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
<type 'float'> <type 'float'> <type 'float'>
Syntax Error.
1.0
(h2hh)~ mgregory$
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to work :( I also did x = float(raw_input())) and that also yielded the same error.

Comment: Works for me.   Program and results added.

Comment: I found my mistake; looks like I was running an older file with a similar name. -.- Thanks for your help and patience!!